# trigger.io topbar, tabbar on mobile web

Tags: trigger.io

I am just digging into trigger.io and have been trying to discover the nuances of what happens to native elements when viewing on the mobile web. So far, I have not been able to get the topbar or tabbar to render. I am assuming that this is because neither are native to the mobile web.

Is there a standard tab bar or tab type system in Trigger that most people use? I am starting off with backbone and zepto as well.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquerymobile has a topbar and footer bar that look pretty similar-ish to the trigger.io iOS and Android native bars.

Like you, I was confused starting out with Trigger.io as to why an equivalent topbar/tabbar was not available when building for web.

Comment: Thanks @Meirion. Seems like the web component of Trigger.io is not as robust as iOS and Android in terms of providing elements and skin components for buttons, forms, etc. Looks like I will still need some additional framework for the web portion (which kind of seems like it reduces the value of Trigger).

Comment: np. Check out Lungo for a slick frontend javascript framework you could consider. I've put their 'kitchen sink' example into a Trigger.io Android app here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758684/lungojs-in-trigger-io/14833837#14833837 - works pretty well