# lungojs in trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io, lungojs

Hi I am looking for using Trigger.io to create mobile app but use the Lungojs for the GUI part. I am unable to find reference of using these two without any issues . would like to hear from some with experience .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interested in Lungo too, so thought the best way would be to try it.

I took the Lungo JS example app from https://github.com/TapQuo/Lungo.js/tree/master/example

Put it into the `/src` folder of a default Trigger.io project and built it for Android without any problems. Tested it on an Android 4.1 device and it works great. :)

The built kitchen sink app is available here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/579708/android/lungojs/lungojskitchensink21.apk

Comment: Turns out the licence for Lungo was too restrictive for my needs as it required my source to be open, or a hefty payment.